# fixed page size on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, mobile, size, fixed

I want to have a web page to be of fixed size of 200px and display full screen on my phone.
So I did a bit of research and used the meta markup in html header :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

I also made a "mobile" css file to fix the body markup size to 200px (and hide overflows) :

```
body
{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

With this I quite got what I need, but for a reason I don't get the page width is still more than 200px. I added a centered text and a sample table with a fixed of 200px to verify this, and got this :

[image: mobile page]

What's wrong with this ?

Full source,
mobile.css:

```
body
{
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

main.css

```
#container
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

table
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}

th, td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

page.php (output HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mobile.css">
        <title>myTitle</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            Sur mobile :)
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Col1</th>
                    <th>Col2</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : removed blank space in the screenshot under the page, added full source

Answer (score 0):

Got a new issue, I wasn't able to scroll down the page. So I removed the overflow:hidden property in the CSS and it fixed both issues.
I still don't get why, however.